# Reference to the Table of Contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing

I thought that someone must have asked this, but my searches didn't find it.

I am looking to refer back to the table of contents from places in my document. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A further improved version that will put two links in every page and links point to the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{linktoc}
\setboolean{linktoc}{true}  %%% uncomment to show answers properly
%\setboolean{linktoc}{false}  %%% comment to show answers properly

\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

\ifthenelse{\boolean{linktoc}}%
{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-70,0){\hyperref[toc]{Go to TOC}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-70,0){\hyperref[toc]{Go to TOC}}}
    }%
}%
{}%


\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents\label{toc}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to display the links (you will in the final document), you can disable them by switching the boolean:

```
%\setboolean{linktoc}{true}  %%% comment to hide links 
\setboolean{linktoc}{false}  %%% uncomment to hide links
```

You get

[image]

Comment: How would I change this to keep the TOC link off my title page?

Comment: @eliyahu-g Try `{\hypersetup{hidelinks} \tableofcontents\label{toc} }`

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using `hyperref` you can simply add a `\label` to the `\tableofcontents` command and then refer to it with `\hyperref`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\label{toc}

\clearpage

\section{A section}

Here is a link to the \hyperref[toc]{Table of Contents}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvoted but realize now after having read [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163972/4686) that `\pageref` does not work correctly if the table of contents extend on more than one page...

Comment: @jfbu In fact I didn't use `\pageref`. `\hyperref` works correctly in any case.

Comment: I did notice you did not use `\pageref`! I was dissuaded from posting an answer when I saw yours, as I thought it nailed it, but then realized about the `\pageref` issue. The OP was not specific and `\pageref` is mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 10):

The normal reference system of LaTeX can be used including packages such as `hyperref`/`nameref`, `titleref`, ...

The tricky part is put `\label` at the right place. `hyperref` likes it right after the title, then the anchor of the `\label` remains the title. Also putting `\label` at the end of the `\tableofcontents` has the risk for a wrong page reference, if the table of contents is more than one page long.

The following example uses an indirect, defensive approach. `\label` is put right at the beginning of the `.toc` file via `\addtocontents`. In the first run, the `\label` goes into the `.toc` file, then in the next run it is propagated to the `.aux` file and in the third LaTeX run the reference is available. Therefore three LaTeX runs are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{toc}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello World}
See table of contents on page \pageref{toc}.
\end{document}
```

The `.toc` file:

```
\label {toc}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Hello World}{1}
```

Result:

> [image: Result]

### Extension, if the table of contents is reused several times

The counter `toclabel` is defined and used to generate several label names, e.g. `toc1`, `toc2`, `toc3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{toclabel}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\stepcounter{toclabel}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{toc\protect\thetoclabel}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{First table of contents}
\input{\jobname.toc}
\newpage
\section*{Second table of contents}
\input{\jobname.toc}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello World}
First table of contents on page \pageref{toc1}\\
Second table of contents on page \pageref{toc2}\\
Third table of contents on page \pageref{toc3}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with several tables of contents]

Comment: Can you please explain what `\protect` does? in `\protect\label{toc}`

Comment: @Kartik See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/35204).

Comment: This will fail if one can typeset multiple times a `table of contents` from the `.toc` file, which admittedly is not the case with the standard classes (and excluding toc-devoted packages).

Comment: @jfbu: This is not much of a problem, see the updated answer.

Comment: you fixed it fast `;-)`...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want a page reference, and you are using a standard class, I would do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldcontentsname\contentsname
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\oldcontentsname\label{contents}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Section 1}

Here is some text for section 1. It refers back to the table of contents 
on page \pageref{contents}.

\clearpage

\section{Section 2}

And here is some more text, also referring to the table of contents on
\pageref{contents}.

\end{document}
```

If `\tableofcontents` doesn't start a new page, you could just issue the `\label` immediately before it, but doing it this way makes sure the label ends up in the right place if a new page is started with the title.

Answer (score 4):

With [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) this works out of the box, with or without `hyperref`:

[image: toc ref]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\label{toc}

\clearpage
\newcount\cnta
\loop
\advance\cnta 1
\ifnum\cnta<100
\section{A section}

Here is a link to the \hyperref[toc]{Table of Contents} on page \pageref{toc}.
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Note that without `etoc` the page reference will be wrong (with or without `hyperref`, the page will be `4` and not the correct `1`). Here is what happens then:

[image: toc ref is wrong]

Comment: And I've upvoted you because your answer seems to solve all issues. :-)

Comment: let's hope it does not create others ... `:)`. [release `1.07k` just to be issued fixes compatibility with `tocloft`]