# Clickable Link back to the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, back-referencing

There are many questions and answers surrounding how to make the `Table of Contents` content clickable. I am wondering how to make a reference to the `Table of Contents` and create a link elsewhere in the document to click on and go back to the table of contents.

I have tried giving the `Table of Contents` its own label via `\tableofcontents\label{toc}` and then using a reference link `\ref{toc}` but this produces the error: `./project.tex:133: Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 133.`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: [Reference to the Table of Contents page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163961/4686)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done with *hypertarget* and *hyperlink* from the *hyperref* package.  See the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Title Page\newpage

% Add a link target to the TOC itself
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}

% Print the TOC
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Sections with a hyperlink to TOC
\section[One]{One. Go to \hyperlink{toc}{TOC}}
Text that points to \hyperlink{toc}{Table of Contents}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection 
\hypertarget{MyToc}{}  % Make an anchor to the toc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Dummy}


\chapter{Yet another Dummy}

Jump to my incredible \hyperlink{MyToc}{Table of contents}

\end{document}
```

Change the relevant documentclass at will.

[image]