# Click chapter to go to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters

Referencing this question: [Hyperref refer chapter and page in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288206/hyperref-refer-chapter-and-page-in-text) and its possible duplicate [Clickable Link back to the Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164285/clickable-link-back-to-the-table-of-contents)

This is basically the second question all over again, but bear with me.

I used the first questions' answer, but shightly edited. I now have every chapter name linking back to the TOC (just the name, not the 'Chapter #' part above it. Not a big problem, if you know how to solve it, lemmeknow :) )

Problem is: this also alters the TOC line itself to link to the TOC. So if I now click a chapter in the TOC, that *also* links to the TOC.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\oldchapter\chapter
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
    \clearpage
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldchapter*{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter*[..]{...}
        {\IfValueTF{#2}
            {\oldchapter[#2]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter[..]{...}
            {\oldchapter{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter{...}
        \label{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1-1]
\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-2]
\end{document}
```

What I did was take the solution with the support for unnumbered chapters, and add a `\hyperref[toc]{}` to them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use `\oldchapter[#3]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}%`, i.e. 
explicitly writing the `#3` again to the toc and setting the `\hyperref` command in the chapter title. This will preserve the the correct hyperanchors and prevents ugly `[toc]` prefixes in the bookmark panel!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldchapter\chapter
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
    \clearpage
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter*[..]{...}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\oldchapter[#2]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter[..]{...}
      {\oldchapter[#3]{\hyperref[toc]{#3}}}% \chapter{...}
      \label{chapter-\thechapter}% \label this chapter
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1-1]
\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-2]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```