# Reference to the Table of Contents page (link in the bottom of the page)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, header-footer

I know that there is the following post

[Reference to the Table of Contents page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163961/reference-to-the-table-of-contents-page)

but I could not find what I want.

What I want is to add in (almost) every page of my document (class book) a reference to the TOC page as below:

[image]

(I don't care for the "jump to Index" link)

All the pages before the TOC would not contain a link.
The same holds true for the first page of each chapter and the first page of the table of contents.

As a minimal working code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table des mati\`eres}

\parindent 0ex

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Dossier de Candidature},
    pdfauthor={Dimitrios S. Anagnostou}]{hyperref}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt

\begin{document}

\title{DOSSIER DE CANDIDATURE}
\author{Dimitrios Papas\thanks{vbkvbkvbdkvbd}}

\affil{
Université\ldots}

\date{\begin{center}
Docteur en Mécanique
\end{center}}

\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter  

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Avant propos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Avant propos} 
\lipsum

\mainmatter  

\chapter{First}

\section{First section}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second}
\section{First section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently you have forgotten to supply the magnifying glass together with your screen shot? And the starter code as well ;-)

Comment: You are right. I apologize. I will put a minimal example and a bigger picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to place a `\label` at the start of the ToC. To achieve this, we force a new page (`\clearpage`) and place a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) marker `\phantomsection`. Now we can place a regular `\label` which we use as a hyperlink in the footer:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter-pages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\hyperref[ToC-first-page]{Jump to Contents}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection% Place hyperlink marker
  \label{ToC-first-page}% Set \label for hyperlink
  \oldtableofcontents
}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \oldmainmatter
  \pagestyle{mainmatter-pages}%
}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Third chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Final chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The process is "automated" by replacing the `\tableofcontents` and `\mainmatter` macros to insert the appropriate links and settings (leaving the regular document code clean).

The footer can be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I run the minimal example with your workaround I get error messages.

Comment: @dimitris: Please [see this paste](http://pastebin.com/FYJ1uEuj) which uses your minimal example with the additions I suggest.

Comment: @Werner It seems not to be absolutely necessary the inclusion of a forced new page... As I'm still a newbie I would like to know if you liked that way for some reason. Thank you

Comment: @Crparedes: The reason for that is a round-about way of latching on to `\tableofcontents`. Under `book`, it necessarily sets a `\chapter*` which forces a new page anyway.